# Android Webview is not showing pop up window

Tags: android, webview

I need in-app browser to hit a URL and authenticate a user,that website pop up a window (on all other browser), but it is not showing pop up on the `WebView`.

**This is my code**

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this issue at Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=752), you should use WebChromeClient within your webview.

```
WebView wv=new WebView(this);   
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: But by doing this app redirect to web browser and we need in-app browser.

Comment: No, it'll not. This method worked for everybody who was involved in that issue which i posted above.

Comment: The above solution didn't solve the problem! Any other solution to display popup in the WebView.